# Putting a Django app under a path on a webserver

Tags: django

I am developing a Django app, and testing it on http://localhost:8000 on the development server.

My urls file has urls in the sorts of:

```
path('somepath1/', myviewclass.function1, name='view_name1'),
path('somepath2/', myviewclass.function2, name='view_name2'),
```

etc...

I have some static links to views in some of the templates using

```
{% url 'view_name1' %}
```

When I navigate the app, as I click links the paths work correctly :
If I goto http://localhost:8000/somepath1/, and then click on a link to another view I get the url : http://localhost:8000/somepath2/

When I put the app on the webserver under the url : http://myserver.com/myapp, as I click the links and submit forms the paths start accumulating.

If I goto http://myserver.com/myapp/somepath1/, and the click on a link to another view I get the url : http://myserver.com/myapp/somepath1/somepath2/, and that is not matched in the urls so I get a 404.

How do I prevent this ?
Thanks
Regards

Comment: How is your app deployed and what web server are you using? The "result" you have included does not have your domain or `myapp` path in the URLs

Comment: I edited the urls on the webserver part. They were a copy paste error. The web server is an apache 2.4. The app is deployed through a cpanel application because this is on a hosting provider. The files are on my home directory on the linux machine, but I don't have access to the mod_wsgi configuration on apache.